# Can NpgsqlTsVector/NpgsqlTsQuery from NpgSql Data Provider be used for Full Text Search?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, npgsql

I'm trying to understand `PostgreSQL` and `Npgsql` in regards to "Full Text Search". Is there something in the Npgsql project that helps doing those searches on a database?

I found the `NpgsqlTsVector.cs/NpgsqlTsQuery.cs` classes in the `Npgsql` source code project. Can they be used for "Full Text Search", and, if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since 3.0.0 Npgsql has special support for PostgreSQL's full text search types (tsvector and tsquery).

Make sure to read the [PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-textsearch.html) and understand the two types and how they work.

Npgsql's support for these types means that it allows you to seamlessly send and receive tsvector and tsquery from PostgreSQL. In other words, you can create an instance of NpgsqlTsVector, populate it with the lexemes you want, and then set it as a parameter in an NpgsqlCommand just like any other parameter type (the same goes for reading a tsvector or tsquery).

For more generic help on using Npgsql to interact with PostgreSQL you can read the [Npgsql docs](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/).